# How to pass coordinates data from a class to another class in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, api

I want to pass coordinates from a class to another one. I am retrieving coordinates from an api. The code looks like the following:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
 
class Test3 extends Component{
    state = {
        loading: true,
        coordinates: null,
    }

    async componentDidMount(){
        const url = "https://ttr.vsbbn.nl:4000/gps_history?team_id=10";
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const data = await response.json();
        this.setState({coordinates: data, loading: false });
        
        
    }

    render(){
        const { loading, coordinates } = this.state
        return(
            <div>
                {loading || !coordinates ? (
                    <div>loading...</div>
                ) : (
                    <div>
                        {coordinates.map((coordinate, index) => {
                             return (
                               <div key={index}>
                                    <p>Longitute: {coordinate.lon}</p>
                                    <p>Latitude: {coordinate.lat}</p>
                                    <p>Time: {coordinate.timestamp}</p>
                                    <p>...............</p>
                               </div>
                               
                             )
                         })}
                    </div>
                )}
                
            </div>
        )
    }

}

export default Test3;
```

And i want to pass the coordinates to the class here below. I already have the path hardcoded in an array. The api coordinates supposed to be in the path array, thats my goal. The code is here:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { 
  GoogleMap, 
  withScriptjs, 
  withGoogleMap, 
  Marker,
  Polyline} 
from 'react-google-maps';
import '../App.css';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom"; 

class Map extends React.Component {
  path = [
    { lat: 18.558908, lng: -68.389916 },
    { lat: 18.558853, lng: -68.389922 },
    { lat: 18.558375, lng: -68.389729 },
    { lat: 18.558032, lng: -68.389182 },
    { lat: 18.55805, lng: -68.388613 },
    { lat: 18.558256, lng: -68.388213 },
    { lat: 18.558744, lng: -68.387929 }
  ];
  render = () => {
    return (
      <GoogleMap
        defaultZoom={16}
        defaultCenter={{ lat: 18.559008, lng: -68.388881 }}
        >
          <Polyline path={this.path} options={{ strokeColor: "#FF0000 " }} />
          <Marker position={this.path[this.path.length - 1]} />
      </GoogleMap>
    )
  }
}

const WrappedMap = withScriptjs(withGoogleMap(Map));

export default() => (  
  <div>
    <br/>
    <b>Klik <Link to="/" className="btn btn-primary">hier</Link> om terug te gaan naar teamoverzicht</b>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <h3>Live kaart</h3>
    <p>
      Teamnaam: Hogeschool Rotterdam 1 <br/>
      Live:<span class="dot"></span><br/>
      Actuele snelheid: 8 km per uur <br/>
      Gemiddelde snelheid: 7 km per uur <br/>
      Verwachte aankomsttijd Rotterdam: 12 mei 17.59 <br/>
    </p>  

    <div style={{width: '50vw', height: '50vh'}}> 
      <WrappedMap googleMapURL = {'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB9w0T_VMezCy1AaqxXpRie9ChrbVCt1O4&v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places'}
      loadingElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
      containerElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
      mapElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
      />
    </div>
  </div>
  )
```

Any idea how to do this? My goal is showing real time the location of a person.

Comment: you can go for Parent Child relationship to move the data from one class to another or else if you don't want relation in the sense use Redux it will help you./

Comment: Pass the data chunk as a prop per each class component

Answer (score 0):

Data passing in React is unidirectional, it means that only a parent can pass props to its child. So if you can nest your component "Map" into "Test3" that will solve it. If you can't do that, then you need to use Redux, which is state management library, that will handle complex data passing between components.
PS: there is way to pass data from a child to its parent, but its very limited (I can send you a tuto if you're interested)

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) documentation, A higher-order component (HOC) is an advanced technique in React for reusing component logic. HOCs are not part of the React API, per se. They are a pattern that emerges from React’s compositional nature

so after you read this doc we are here to answer all of your questions about it.

Answer (score 0):

you need to save the coordinates in an ordered way (to your state) that you could pass it to the children components (in your case `<Map />`).

in the `componentDidMount` of your `<Test3 />` component try this:

```
async componentDidMount(){
   const url = "https://ttr.vsbbn.nl:4000/gps_history?team_id=10";
   const response = await fetch(url);
   const data = await response.json();

   const coordinatesList = []
   data.forEach(coor => {
      coordinatesList.push({ lat: coor.lat, lng: coor.lng })
   })

   this.setState({coordinates: coordinatesList, loading: false });      
}
```

this would result something like below:

```
coordinatesList: [
    { lat: someNumber, lng: someNumber },
    { lat: someNumber, lng: someNumber },
    { lat: someNumber, lng: someNumber },
    ...
]
```

after that inside of render function you can pass the `coordinatesList` state to your child component and use it, something like

```
<Map coorList={coordinatesList} />
```

no need to loop over coordinates! you need to do what ever you want inside the map component wityh all of your coordinates. (as a side note i'm thinking that you try to create markers of those coordinates, so you need to loop over `coorList` props that you've been received from your parent and return a `<Marker />` component of each of that coordinates )

Comment: Thanks for your answer so far. I just put <Map coorList={coordinatesList} /> in the render function in the component <Test3/>. But it shows an error: Line 28:35:  'coordinatesList' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: add this to your state `coordinatesList`, please read how logic flows, not just copy past what ever i wrote there :))))

Comment: I think i add `coordinatesList` to the state. It looks like: `this.setState({coordinates: coordinatesList, loading: false });`   I still having the error

Comment: log the `coordinatesList` to check what it is

Answer (score 0):

Another option could be use use react context/provider, which would serve as a container for your data and also any functions to update the data. Your context could be accessed from both components and gives you the same single source of data that redux gives you, without all the boilerplate code that goes with redux.

Create a provider component and a use context hook

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react'

const Context = createContext({})

// This is your provider
const MapDataProvider = props => {
  const [mapData, setMapData] = useState([...your original coordinates])

  useEffect(() => {
    ...your call to google
      .then(data, setMapData(current => [...current, data])
  }, [])

  return (
    <Context.Provider value={{coordinates: mapData}}>
      {props.children}
    </Context.Provider>
  )
}

// This is your hook
const useMapDataContext = () => useContext(Context)

export { MapDataProvider, useMapDataContext }
```

Wrap the exported Provider around your root component

```
import { MapDataProvider } from './yourcontextfile.js'

const RootComponent = () => (
  <MapDataProvider>
    <Test3/>
    <WrappedMap/>
    ...whatever, the structure here is not important
  </MapDataProvider>
)
```

Then in any of your components where you need to access the data, you use the exported hook `useMapDataContext`

```
import { useMapDataContext } from './yourcontextfile.js'

const Test3 = () => {
  // This is deconstructed from the value prop on the provider component
  const { coordinates } = useMapDataContext()

  ... the rest of your component
}
```

I haven't compiled or tested any of this, it's just a quick example of how you could use a context component to have your data in one place, accessible from any other component, as long as it's inside the `<MapDataProvider>` component.

I'm not saying it's the right way to do it, it's just another way.